# Does Hausdorff measure have a physical meaning?

Tags: measure-theory, physics, intuition, mathematical-physics, hausdorff-measure

Although Hausdorff measure provides a reasonable way to approach general metric space including fractal geometry, I do not really realize how they actually get meanings in the physical world.

May I ask for some examples where the connection between Hausdorff measure and physical phenomenon has been observed?

I meant some concrete properties like mass, conductivity, or probability distribution associated with Hausdorff measure.
Any measures having such realization other than Lebesgue and probability measures will be also helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Its coincides with the surface measure for manifolds embedded in real space, so in some sense it generalises surface measures to non-integral dimensions

Comment: @pax Very interesting, but could you describe some more details?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that people don't believe that fractal geometry has application in real world constructs, but that isn't the case.  Consider the "length" of coastlines -- different texts have vastly different measurements for the length of a coastline depending on the scale at which it was measured, because coastlines are somewhat fractal in nature, even though they are real physical objects.  The west coast of Ireland has been calculated to have a Hausdorff dimension of roughly 1.26, while the east coast of Ireland has a Hausdorff dimension of roughly 1.10.  This tells you that (a) it is almost pointless to measure the linear distance of these coastlines, since they are fractal and will measure "longer" the smaller the scale you use, but also that (b) the west coast is "more crinkly" than the east coast.  Hausdorff dimension gives a way to measure concretely how much more "folded in on itself" an object, curve, or other things to be measured might be, including real world objects.

Comment: +1 when you mention folding, it reminds me of our brain. A web search indicate cerebral cortex is a fractal with dimension 2.7-2.8.... So our brain is more crinkly than the coastlines...

Comment: Very true, but before we get a big head about it... broccoli and cauliflower are equally crinkly. :)

Comment: I wonder, however, about some more intrinsic properties like the aforementioned conductivity or probabilistic behaviors. Well, I found some occurrence of Hausdorff dimension in random walks in fractal networks, but I hope there are more cases.

Answer (score 0):

$n$-dimensional Hausdorff measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ coincides with Lebesgue measure. For $m < n$, $m$-dimensional Hausdorff measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ coincides with the standard surface measure on embedded manifolds $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. The standard surface measure is the one that defines formulas for length of curve, area of surface, etc. that you compute in calculus class.

Comment: Can we verify if that standard surface measure really 'measures' some physical properties like travel distance, electric current, or heat flow? Please excuse me for being doubtful; I want some more concrete examples as a physicist.

Comment: @BStar You can use Riemann sums and intuitive linear algebra stuff to derive the general surface measure formula. For example we have that if $\phi : (0, 1) \to \mathbb{R^n}$ is $C^1$ with nonzero derivative at each point, then the length of $\phi((0, 1))$ is $\int_0^1 \lVert \phi'(t) \rVert \,dt$. You see this formula in many calculus texts as the definition of the length of a curve along with a heuristic derivation. The surface measure gives the definition for all embedded manifolds.

Comment: @Bstar For area of surfaces and flux, you get a formula involving cross product. That is also the surface measure. I saw this one in physics too.

Comment: I am still wondering more about it, but seems it is now in my hands to investigate. Many thanks for the ideas. They will be really helpful.